# Inline Event Handler in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf-controls, inline

I create textbox controls dynamically through code behind. I have to bind a handker on 'LostFocus' event of the newly created textbox. And then add it to a Listbox.  I am able to do this with below code.

```
TextBox txtBox = new TextBox();
txtBox.Text ="XXXX";
txtBox.Width = 100;
txtBox .LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(updateTextHandler);
listBox.Items.Add(txtBox);
```

But, I want to shorten this code and do like

```
listServer.Items.Add(new TextBox()
                {
                    Text = "XXXXX",
                    Width = 100

                });
```

How do I add event handler for the controls initialized inline? I tried, but doesn't work

```
this.LostFocus +=new RoutedEventHandler(updateButtonHandler)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx):

> Object initializers let you assign values to any accessible fields or properties of an object at creation time

Events aren't fields or properties so you can't set them in initializer. Especially as they are not accessible by `=` but only by `+=`.